# What went wrong with JVM GC when I launch spark-shell in a shared login node?

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am running spark-shell in one a HPC login-node (a node shared by multiple users so the admin has set some resource limits for each user)

When I launch spark-shell from command line (I am using `bin/spark-shell` shipped with pyspark 3.0.1, without any arguments)

The error shown when i run `spark-shell -v`:

```
Main class:
org.apache.spark.repl.Main
Arguments:

Spark config:
(spark.jars,)
(spark.app.name,Spark shell)
(spark.submit.pyFiles,)
(spark.ui.showConsoleProgress,true)
(spark.submit.deployMode,client)
(spark.master,local[*])
Classpath elements:



Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
```

I got this core dump file:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 16 bytes for AllocateHeap
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.inline.hpp:61), pid=428290, tid=0x00002ac0965dd700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_191-b12) (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.191-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Core dump written. Default location: /my/working/dir/tmp/core or core.428290
#

...
...

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 281600K, used 39809K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 262144K, 7% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ebf30088,0x00000000fab00000)
  from space 19456K, 98% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fbdb0540,0x00000000fbe00000)
  to   space 67584K, 0% used [0x00000000fbe00000,0x00000000fbe00000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 77181K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 699392K, 11% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c4b5f460,0x00000000eab00000)
 Metaspace       used 72906K, capacity 78552K, committed 78848K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 9013K, capacity 9377K, committed 9472K, reserved 1048576K
```

It seems like either part 2 of 'PSYoungGen' or ClassSpace gets full?

I am not falimiiar with Java (I am not developping in java, instead I just want to launch Application correctly)

Here is my ulimit info:

```
$ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 380195
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 16384
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 300
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 8388608
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

And my memoryinfo (cat /proc/meminfo)

```
MemTotal:       97353940 kB
MemFree:         4565860 kB
MemAvailable:   31438168 kB
Buffers:          527764 kB
Cached:         73469304 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         50002012 kB
Inactive:       30665992 kB
Active(anon):   49118320 kB
Inactive(anon):  1973220 kB
Active(file):     883692 kB
Inactive(file): 28692772 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:             14092 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       6671608 kB
Mapped:           382268 kB
Shmem:          44418868 kB
Slab:            9548096 kB
SReclaimable:     752440 kB
SUnreclaim:      8795656 kB
KernelStack:       54816 kB
PageTables:       186136 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    48676968 kB
Committed_AS:   56368676 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:     1638408 kB
VmallocChunk:   34307690768 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   1048576 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      505664 kB
DirectMap2M:    32661504 kB
DirectMap1G:    68157440 kB
```

Note that if I use one of the compute node (allocated to me solely, instead of shared with other users). Spark-shell runs correctly.

I want to know why I have sufficient memory, so that I could contact admin to adjust the limits. Or if there is some javaoptions I should use, that will be great to.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: perhaps running `spark-shell --verbose` can provide you some hints?

Comment: @mazaneicha, thanks i edited the post, --verbose gave me: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace"

Comment: Can you check `/etc/spark/conf/` contains what it should (spark-defaults.conf, spark-env.sh...), because empty spark.jars in `Spark config:
(spark.jars,)` doesnt look right.

Answer (score 2):

You have virtual memory limit set in place

```
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 8388608
```

This option limits total size of address space reservation. JVM tend to reserve address space ahead of time for most memory areas.

You can reduce total amount of memory reserved by JVM by reducing max size of various non heap spaces. Below are few suggestions.

- `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m`
- `-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=128m`

Lifting up virtual memory limit for user is better solution though. Amount of virtual memory on 64 bit system is "virtually" unlimited. Other types of memory limits are not working in Linux, though, so admins have little choice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the HPC in under maintainance for two days, I will update how it goes once I get the access to it.

Comment: I tried both options but it doesn't seem help.. What i found interesting is that i can enter Spark shell with "./bin/spark-shell --driver-java-options="-XX:+PrintGCDetails" --driver-memory=512m" (by default, driver memory is 1GB)
But if I just run "./bin/spark-shell  --driver-memory=512m" , it gave the out of memory in metaspace again.